# Array printing one character at a time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my array, when I print it, it shows up `['item', 'item_Two']` and so on, but if I try to get an individual one using `print(list[0])` it shows the first letter, which if its "i" then it prints `i` and if I do `print(list[1])` then it prints `t` and so on. If needed, I can give the code that I'm using to get the array, I just didn't know if it made sense because it has webhooks and uses discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import pickle


client = commands.Bot("-")
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("message"):
        await message.channel.send("hello there")
    if message.content.startswith("webhook"):
        content = "\n".join([f"{w.url}" for w in await message.guild.webhooks()])
        webhook_urls = [w.url for w in await message.guild.webhooks()]
        print (webhook_urls)
        pickle.dump(content, open("boturllist.dat", "wb"))
        await message.channel.send("Saved Webhooks to file")


client.run('token')
```

And then to get the array, i do the following.

```
urllist = pickle.load(open("boturllist.dat", "rb"))
print(urllist)
```

I apologize for all of the confusion. It turns out I was editing the wrong file. Thank you to everyone who helped out.

Comment: bro, please explain more, I cannot find a place where the first letter is `t`

Comment: @jsotola @KuldeepSinghSidhu I forgot to change that, i will edit it. Before the things in the array were `['thing1', 'thing2']` Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: can you provide some more context. I am not able to reproduce your problem

Comment: I think it'll be better if you shared the code snippet which is actually causing the issue.

Comment: @Athos I will edit the question to show my code. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: you can *must* provide a [mcve]

Comment: are you certain that the quotation marks are the same on both sides of `'item'`?

Comment: @Athos I edited the question to show my code.

Comment: Where is the code that prints `list[0]` and gets the incorrect value?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're getting mixed up between `content` and `webhook_urls`. `content[0]` will be the first character, while `webhook_urls[0]` is the whole URL.

Comment: Hmm have never worked with discord bots. But the first thing that come to my mind is a mixup in between `content` and `webhooks_urls`. As far as i know, `.join` will return a value of type `string` which would explain the behaviour u are getting in the `print(list[0])` statment.

Comment: @Athos it seems to be a problem with the Pickle library messing with the array when its saved. Any suggestions? It needs to save the URLs and open in another script.

Comment: @EchoTheAlpha Are u absolutley sure about that? Because `content` seems to be a `string` not a `array`. If it is a problem with the pickle library i can maybe suggest to use Json instead.